# Постановка запятой после слова "есть"

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, будьте добры, нужна ли запятая (ситуация при управлении кораблем):

*- Принять влево на сто двадцать три.*

*- Есть, сто двадцать три.*

То есть в ответ на указание командира. Вроде "есть, капитан" в военном дело, например.

Answer (score 2):

[ЕСТЬ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x)
**3. ЕСТЬ, *межд.*** Воен. Ответ подчинённого, обозначающий, что команда понята и принята к исполнению. *Сняться с якоря! — Есть сняться с якоря!*

Ответ на приказ, думаю, должен быть повторен слово в слово; запятая не ставится.

**— Принять влево на сто двадцать три.

— Есть принять влево на сто двадцать три.**
[Или "Есть влево на сто двадцать три".]

*— Принять вправо! — Есть принять вправо!* (В. Коротин. Флоту — побеждать!)

*— Не рыскать, — делает замечание капитан. — Точнее держать.

— Есть точнее держать!

— Пять вправо, — спокойно командует капитан.

— Есть пять вправо!*
([Г. Гусаченко. Под крылом Ангела-хранителя](https://books.google.ee/books?id=UEWuomgAIPAC&pg=PA65&lpg=PA65&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=DUSh3VOBYu&sig=ACfU3U3bxUMlY8Ad7VFFtQ7orN3EHMWGMA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR8oad4trjAhWFtYsKHeI7BZYQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE&f=false))

P. S. *Есть, капитан!* — запятая ставится при обращении.